# Why Moving Average is not being visible as intended in this case

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to draw SMA on my candle stick charts .

This is my code

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


var mydata = [
    ['13-Oct', 1097.95, 1113.45, 1109.95, 1132],
    ['14-Oct', 1095.6, 1101.15, 1113.45, 1117],
    ['15-Oct', 1092.1, 1129.2, 1116, 1132],
    ['16-Oct', 1130, 1170.3, 1130, 1182.4],
    ['19-Oct', 1144.5, 1162.15, 1174, 1182.2]
];


function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mydata, true);

    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        colors: ['red', 'brown'],
        candlestick: {
            fallingColor: {
                fill: "orange",
                strokeWidth: 0.5,
                stroke: 'black'
            },
            risingColor: {
                fill: "yellowgreen",
                strokeWidth: 0.5,
                stroke: 'black'
            }
        }
    };


    var days = 5;
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, {
        type: 'number',
        label: days + '-day Moving Average',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            // calculate average of closing value for last x days,
            // if we are x or more days into the data set
            if (row >= days - 1) {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
                    total += data.getValue(row - i, 3);
                }
                var avg = total / days;
                return {v: avg, f: avg.toFixed(2)};
            }
            else {
                // return null for < x days
                return null;
            }
        }
    }]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(view, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        chartArea: {
            left: '7%',
            width: '70%'
        },
        series: {
            0: {
                type: 'candlesticks'
            },
            1: {
                type: 'line'
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Could you please tell me how to make SMA visible properly ??

Before adding SMA everything was working with my datapoints .

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ovog4njt/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *SMA* line is not visible because the calculated column is returning `null` for the first four rows, zero for the last.

In the `calc` function, `row` starts at zero.
With `days = 5`, `if (row >= days - 1)` doesn't pass until the last row...

I'm a little confused how you want to calculate the moving average but I took a shot.

Using the fourth column in the data, I calculate the average as such...

> Row 0: Value: 1,109.95
>   Row 1: Value: 1,111.70 --> (1,109.95 + 1,113.45) / 2
>   Row 2: Value: 1,113.13 --> (1,109.95 + 1,113.45 + 1,116.00) / 3
>   etc...

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var mydata = [
    ['13-Oct', 1097.95, 1113.45, 1109.95, 1132],
    ['14-Oct', 1095.6, 1101.15, 1113.45, 1117],
    ['15-Oct', 1092.1, 1129.2, 1116, 1132],
    ['16-Oct', 1130, 1170.3, 1130, 1182.4],
    ['19-Oct', 1144.5, 1162.15, 1174, 1182.2]
];

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mydata, true);
    var days = mydata.length;
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, {
        type: 'number',
        label: days + '-day Moving Average',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            // calculate average of closing value for last x days,
            // if we are x or more days into the data set
            var avg = 0;
            var total = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i <= row; i++) {
              total = total + data.getValue(i, 3);
            }
            avg = total / (row + 1);
            return {v: avg, f: avg.toFixed(2)};
        }
    }]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(view, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        chartArea: {
            left: '7%',
            width: '70%'
        },
        series: {
            0: {
                type: 'candlesticks'
            },
            1: {
                type: 'line'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hope this helps, if this is incorrect, please describe the exact calculation for the moving average...

Comment: Thanks a lot , i was able to generate Candlestick charts successfully ,but when  i need to show SimpleMovingAreage also 

which would be this way 

For Example for 3 data points say 

100 , 105 , 106 it would be 


100+105+106/3 which is exactly what you did .

Comment: I need to show 5 , 10 , 30 day SMA at once , is that possible ??

Comment: I have modified the answer to use the number of rows in the data to determine the number of days, so this answer should now work for any number of days...

Comment: Thanks a lot i was working on your code but i came across this issue please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ovog4njt/17/ , The 10 day SMA Average should be 560.23

But why it is displaying 552 ??

Comment: when I run the calculation manually in Excel using the data from the fourth column in the fiddle I get --> 552.245

Comment: Thank you for your reponse i have taken all close prices and created this fiddle of above data https://jsfiddle.net/sxj9fbcm/ to say that avg is 560 . please see this so i guess somewhere the calculation is going wrong .

Comment: the last fiddle is correct and works because that is the data from the third column in the previous fiddle. whereas I was calculating the fourth in my last comment. I think you're good, as long as you have the right column...

Comment: its not your mistake  what i wanted to say ,  total = total + data.getValue(i, 2); works great .

Comment: thanks a lot for guiding me along to complete this task for me .